# React App Axios route unrecognizable after deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, devops

I have an application built on react and express.

1. Even though I've specified to run heroku port or my local port if I were to run it local, somehow, I get an error saying my `axios.post('/',...)` has a `POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)`, where app still uses 3000 instead of 8000.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App running on port ', port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

2. Can someone also advice me what should I be putting in my package.json so that I'm able to run my application on both heroku and locally? Also what would be command instead of `npm start`? Here's my Current Project Directory and package.json:

```
-> index.js
  -> src
    -> containers
      -> App.js (My react frontend)
    -> server
      -> server.js (My express backend)
```

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server/server.js",
    // "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: Do you have a github repo we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

> First Question:
>
> I am guessing you are using a proxy. The reason why it continues to
>   point at localhost:3000 is because you still have cache.To clear the
>   cache, you are going to need to first delete the node_modules folder
>   and package-lock.json in your react app. Second npm install all the
>   dependencies again to your react app and restart your react terminal.
>   After that, your proxy should work.

Second Question:

I don't recommend using your react's package.json . It much prefer to use your server's package.json , because it won't interfere with the react start script and anyway your server is suppose to be the one serving the build's static content. An easy and good method is putting your entire server folder in the root directory.

Not a lot of people talk about this;but there is a order heroku runs your scripts

1. `heroku-prebuild` script  =>  Runs before heroku install dependencies
2. npm install              =>  Install the packages in your package.json
3. `heroku-postbuild` script  =>  Runs after heroku install dependencies
4. `start` script             =>  Runs after step 1,2,3 are completed

Typically people will use the `heroku-postbuild` script to run their `npm run build`

Comment: Do I need to reconfigure my package.json? Also, could you share a guide/link to that's most relevant to my problem? That would help alot. Previously, I already tried deploying on heroku with my ```server.js``` in the root directory, same level as package.json. Did `npm build` etc but things didn't quite work. I also face the issue where I have to disable minification of react app which I can't resolve.

To be honest, the is the first I encounter such problems and made such changes so its quite foreign to me to follow.